# Inserting line break in-between JSF inputText and outputText components

Tags: java, html, jsf, jsf-2

I'm having a difficult time with something that should be pretty simple.

I can't get my browser (Firefox operating on Ubuntu 16.04) to respect a `<br>` tag.  The application server is tomcat 7 embedded in my Java app.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml"
      xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <h:head>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <form action="/portal/form" method="POST" id="myform">
            <h:outputText value="Please enter the requested credit card and billing information below"/>
            <label>
                <span>Address</span>
                <h:inputText class="field" id="address1" />
                <br></br>
                <h:outputText value="City" /> <h:inputText class="field" id="city"/>
                <h:outputText value="State" /> <h:inputText class="field" id="state" />
                <h:outputText value="zip" /> <h:inputText class="field" id="zipcode" />
            </label>

            <button type="submit">Pay $25</button>
        </form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

You will notice I included the closing `<br>` tag.  That's because I got an error without it.

The browser simply shows one text field after another on the same line without any breaks.

> Error Traced[line: 37] The element type "br" must be terminated by the
>   matching end-tag "".

So, how can I get it to respect the line break?

**EDIT 1** I tried `<br/>` again and didn't get any errors, however it's not interpreting it as a line break.  It generates `<br />` in the HTML source code.

Comment: br is a self closing tag. It should be `<br/>`

Comment: Have you tried <br/>?

Comment: I tried <br/> as well and it gave me the same error.

Comment: Try to remove the wrapping <label> tags. Wrapping that whole content block in a label doesn't make sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. As indicated by the error message, it definitely suppose to be: **`<br />`**.
2. Then go into your browser developer console (eg. Firebug) and check the `display` attribute of the `<label>` tag. You probably have to set it via css style to `display: inline-block;` *(see following example)*.

---

#### Example 1 (probably your case)

You probably have some kind of `flex` setting for the `display` attribute. That would look like that:

```css
label {
  display: flex;
}
input { width: 50px; }
```

```html
<label>
    <span>Address</span>
    <input type="text" class="field" id="address1" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" value="City" />
    <input type="text" value="State" /> 
    <input type="text" value="zip" />
</label>

<button type="submit">Pay $25</button>
```

#### Example 2 (how it works)

If you set the display attribute as described above you get the wished result.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block; /* check the display attribute! */
}
input { width: 50px; }
```

```html
<label>
    <span>Address</span>
    <input type="text" class="field" id="address1" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" value="City" />
    <input type="text" value="State" /> 
    <input type="text" value="zip" />
</label>

<button type="submit">Pay $25</button>
```

---

#### EDIT

Check also that the tag `<br />` has not the `display` attribute `none`. That also elements the line break.

```css
br { display:none; }
```

```html
Test <br /> test
```